# Excel VBA: Error when concatenating in the filename and exporting into PDF FORMAT

Tags: vba, excel

What I am trying to do is to save the activesheet as PDF file in a folder contained in dropbox (also a folder). The idea is for the name to incorporate the date (Which is contained in a variable). I got the 1004 error and it says that the file might be already opened or that an error happened while saving. If I don't try to concatenate, then it works but that doesn't work for me because I need the date to be changing daily. I have tried many ways and none of them work. Help please =(

```
Dim dato_fechador As Variant
Dim file_name As Variant
dato_fechador = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
file_name = "C:\Users\Juan Pablo Zegers\Dropbox\Japanese\Práctica\" & dato_fechador & ".pdf"
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=file_name, _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
End Sub
```

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7vGn.jpg)

Comment: Can you place a break right before the last command you have shared? Once the code stops on that line can you check what value `file_name` is using?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the backslash from the end of your file name, "C:\Users\Juan Pablo Zegers\Dropbox\Japanese\Práctica"

Comment: Thank you!! I knew it was something like that. I kept fighting for hours hahahaha. Thank you sooooo much!